# Can't get Cocoapods to work in a mixed Ruby Environment (OSX Sierra)

Tags: ruby, macos, cocoapods, homebrew, rvm

So I'm running OSX Sierra and I have a couple of Rails apps installed and Ruby 2.3.1 installed using rvm.

This seems to have created some sort of a conflict with Cocoapods which was installed using Homebrew (brew install cocoapods).  Orginally I ran into the error that thread_safe wasn't installed... so I installed that (gem install thread_safe) THEN i ran into the problem that i18n wasn't installed... so I installed that... but I keep getting the error that it ISN'T installed.

It looks like cocoapods is trying to run another ruby version (2.6.5) from /usr/bin/ while it's simultaneously trying to run gems from 2.3.1.

I have NO IDEA how to fix this. Any help would be appreciated:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    19: from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.8.4/libexec/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
    18: from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.8.4/libexec/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    17: from /Users/rainless/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/bin/pod:36:in `<top (required)>'
    16: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    15: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    14: from /Users/rainless/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
    13: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    12: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    11: from /Users/rainless/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    10: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
     9: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
     8: from /Users/rainless/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.1/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
     7: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
     6: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
     5: from /Users/rainless/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.1/lib/active_support/inflections.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
     4: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
     3: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
     2: from /Users/rainless/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.1/lib/active_support/inflector/inflections.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
     1: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- thread_safe (LoadError)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well THIS was a fun one.  Something screwed up must've happened when I tried to run:

```
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods
```

Probably should've just run: "brew install cocoapods" but it's been a LONG time since I've run Homebrew.  I almost forgot the "brew" command existed.

Anyway it became confused about which version of ruby I was using so I fixed this by making a .ruby-gemset file:

**.ruby-gemset**

```
homebrew
```

...and a .ruby-version file:

**.ruby-version**

```
ruby-2.3.3
```

After that it was a simple matter of running "gem install bundler" and "bundle install" with

```
gem 'cocoapods'
```

...in the Gemfile.

That was it! Now Cocoapods works just fine and it's using the version of Ruby that I want it to use.